# SSSD on docker container (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, docker-container, freeipa, sssd

I am trying to integrate ubuntu docker container with  FreeIPA and getting below error while installing FreeIPA-client --install

```
Created /etc/ipa/default.conf
New SSSD config will be created
Configured sudoers in /etc/nsswitch.conf
Configured /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
Configured /etc/krb5.conf for IPA realm BLABS.COM
trying https://vilma.com/ipa/json
Forwarding 'ping' to json server 'https://vilma.com/ipa/json'
Forwarding 'ca_is_enabled' to json server 'https://vilma.com/ipa/json'
Systemwide CA database updated.
Adding SSH public key from /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
Adding SSH public key from /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
Adding SSH public key from /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
Adding SSH public key from /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
Forwarding 'host_mod' to json server 'https://vilma/ipa/json'
SSSD enabled
SSSD service restart was unsuccessful.
Configured /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
Unable to find 'admin' user with 'getent passwd admin@vilma.com'!
Unable to reliably detect configuration. Check NSS setup manually.
NTP enabled
```

I tried to start sssd manually by typing sssd and getting below message

```
 ldb: unable to open modules directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb' - Permission denied
 (Sun Oct 14 20:55:17:078716 2018) [sssd] [load_configuration] (0x0010): The confdb initialization failed
(Sun Oct 14 20:55:17:078750 2018) [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this, the problem is that the `overlayfs` that docker uses causes problems with the `ldb` database that `sssd` is using.

So you need to:

1. move `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb` to another path (e.g. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb-orig`) in your Dockerfile
2. then, before starting `sssd` in your container, you have to create an empty volume and mount it into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb`
3. then copy the original contents of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb` from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb-orig` into the new volume
4. then start `sssd`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed with Linux 5.8. I think it was this [fix](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200408085423.GA21974@miu.piliscsaba.redhat.com/), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -3):

I could able to manage workaround by not using sssd (--no-sssd option)

Comment: How can be considered an answer? It's just a poor workaround.

Comment: I understand, it's just it can't be  considered a solution, as you said...